# Get current template's last modified date without accessing HDD

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I know I can use `getFileInfo(getCurrentTemplatePath())` to get the current template's last modified date, but it would be better if I could just grab it from memory. I have several possible uses in mind, but I'm not ready to defend them yet, so for now let's just say I'm asking out of curiosity.

I assume the application server must check the modified date at some point to decide if it needs to compile. If I have to use the underlying Java to get to it, that's fine (a pure CF approach would be better, of course, but I'm not holding out much hope).

If the modified date isn't available, then I'd settle for some sort of flag indicating if the current request triggered a recompile (actually, that might work just as well).

Comment: I believe it will only check the date on each request if you tell the server to do that. Otherwise, it will load the template into the template cache and retrieve it from there the next time it's loaded. Therefore, if it's even possible to get the date, it would only work in a non-production environment (assuming you have that feature turned off for production)

Comment: @Redtopia For better or worse, we don't precompile anything (I didn't even realize that was an option, tbh), so templates are always compiled on first request after any modification. Even if they weren't, I'd be a little surprised if there wasn't some sort of record of when the templates were last modified, compiled or cached, buried somewhere in the server's memory.

Comment: And just to be clear, if I can't get the last modified date, then I'd settle for the next closest thing, whatever that may be. If I could determine when the server started using whatever version of the template it's currently serving to client, that would be good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader`. It handles the lookup against the `TemplateCache` and either fetches an already compiled template class or invokes `coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator` to compile CFML into it.

```
<cfset templateUri  = getCurrentTemplatePath()>
<cfset lastCompiled = createObject("java", "coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader").getLastCompiledTime(templateUri)>
<!--- lastCompiled = unix timestamp in milliseconds --->
```

**Needless to say**, this is an implementation detail and you should not rely on it.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was looking for! I've been playing around with persistent scopes and cfcache, as well as dynamic CSS and JavaScript, and it occurred to me that this info could be used to determine if a refresh is needed. Worst case scenario if it ever stopped working is that the refresh would happen every time. Thanks for your help!